# Is it possible to get the caller object of a closure in groovy?

Tags: groovy, closures

Is it possible to get a reference of the `Object` that invoked a `Closure` in the `Closure`'s execution context?

For example:

```
public class Example {

    public Example(){
        def a = {return this};
        def b = [];

        b.metaClass.a = a;

        println b.a();
    }
}
```

I want this execution to return `b` instead of an instance of `Example`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The object that the closure is invoked on can be referenced as `delegate`.  Example:

```
def a = { return delegate }
def b = []

b.metaClass.a = a

assert b.a() == b
```